# Sorting ArrayList Based on Value of Long

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I am attempting to sort an ArrayList based on the value of a long present within each object. After following various examples around the internet, I have come up with the following code but it is not sorting as desired (it seems to truncate parts of the object).

```
public static Comparator<Customer> compareSIN = 
         new Comparator<Customer>() {
            public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer other) {
               String sin1 = "" + cust1.sin;
               String sin2 = "" + other.sin;
               return sin1.compareTo(sin2);
            }
         };
```

Please advise me on what I am doing missing in the first snippet of code that is preventing me from sorting the objects properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the title I assume `Customer.sin` is a `long` - and the problem is you are trying to compare them as `String`s rather then by their numeric value.

(Example: 10000 is lexicographically smaller then 2 - so using `String`s here is the fault)

You should use [`Long.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare%28long,%20long%29) (Assuming java 7):

```
public static Comparator<Customer> compareSIN = 
         new Comparator<Customer>() {
            public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer other) {
               return Long.compare(cust1.sin,other.sin);
            }
         };
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please clarify what the syntax would be for Long.compare()?

Comment: Why use Long.compare() over a simple subtraction?  Im curious.

Comment: @JonTaylor: Readability, mainly - it is much clearer what `Long.compare(x,y)` does then subtraction (from first look on it). Also it is usually more maintainable.

Comment: Is that really the only reason? because I would have to say that is a pretty bad reason to make another method call.  I can't believe this would be the sole reason for Java 7 including this comparator?  Readability of a subtraction for comparison is not really an issue as it is extremely basic.

Comment: @JonTaylor: IMHO, these are the main reasons, but I could be wrong of course. Don't worry about "another method calls" - any jvm is most likely to jit optimize it. Remember that micro optimizations is for compilers, while readability is for programmers.

Comment: good point however I don't really find it any more readable.  Maybe for someone who's been programming for a very short period of time, however for any programmer with more than a few weeks experience I would honestly be baffled if they found the subtraction any less readable.

Comment: Long subtraction wont work when the return value of the compareTo method is int. The compiler will complain about loss of precision. Makes sense because the subtracted value might overflow integer.

Comment: Thanks @Kal - it is indeed an important issue! Makes the naive subtraction wrong. A good example will be: `(int) ((((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1) - 0l)`

Comment: @JonTaylor: See Kal's insight on the reason why substraction is wrong. This is exactly the reason to prefer built in libraries when possible - someone already thought on whatever we don't.

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought of this issue.  I agree somewhat on using libraries when possible however I have seen many libraries get implementations wrong when you would assume they test test test.  Relying on the fact a library will give you the correct answer is imo bad practice.  You should test it as much either way.  Aside the testing issue, it is clear this new comparator was put in for this reason and not readability as you stated above.

Comment: @JonTaylor I *think* the comparator also exists for int types as Integer.compare(int,int) (not at home currently to verify it, so going from memory)

Answer (score 2):

You do not actually need to use a `compareTo()` method inside your own `compareTo()` method.

The compare to states that it must return 0 if they are equal and negative or positive numbers for non equality.

For this reason you can compare two longs by returning the one subtracted from the other.

```
public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer other) {
           return cust1.sin - other.sin;
}
```

This will as you can see, return 0 if they are equal, negative if *other.sin* is greater than *cust1.sin* and positive if *cust1.sin* is greater than *other.sin*.

Comment: I think he wants to compare them as String... if i'm not mistaken

Comment: I think he was converting to a string because it had a compareTo method available.  From his title and description he wants to compare the long values.  What would comparing the string representations achieve?

Comment: nothing to my taste but i assumed he was converting to String on some kind of purpose

Comment: @foampile I had only converted to string because .compareTo does not work with long and for some reason, I didn't think of subtraction.

Comment: See comment provided by @Kal on my answer why the naive substraction is problematic

Answer (score 0):

You compare `String`s instead of `long`s.

So, imagine you want to compare : "10" and "5", outcome would be **"10"  < "5"** whereas thinking that you're working with `long`, you expect to get **10 > 5** ...

That can explain your issue.